# Is ok to perform ordering operation on Property? Is there a better way of doing it?

Tags: c#, .net-core, domain-driven-design

I need to have a collection ordered by a score and maintain its position number. I'm doing it like this:

```
private readonly ICollection<Score> _winningTable = new List<Score>();

public IEnumerable<Score> WinningTable
{
    get
    {
        var orderedList = _winningTable.OrderByDescending(w => w.Score).ToList();
        orderedList.ForEach(w =>
        {
            var index = orderedList.IndexOf(w);

            // This will edit the object position and score
            w.EditScore((decimal)w.Score, index + 1);
        });

        return orderedList.ToList();
    }
}
```

In the property I'm maintaining the order and setting its position nbr. So I'm only accessing the object winning scores via that property.
I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way of doing it and I wanted to know if there's some better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I see your requirements:

1. You need the WinningTable property to always represent an ordered list of your scores.
2. You need each score to keep its position index inside the list.

Based on the second requirement, I assume each Score can only be inside a single `WinningTable` at any given time. Because otherwise what would its position index be?

I believe your implementation has some problems:

1. Nothing stops you from adding a single Score object to multiple `WinningTables`. In which case its position index will not be what you would expect.
2. Due to the *Lazy Evaluation* nature of `IEnumerable`s, when I see an `IEnumerable` property, I don't expect retrieving it to be a *costy* operation. However, in your getter you iterate the list entirely which is not expected to happen when you only need to retrieve the `IEnumerable`. In other words, when I do this: `var scores = obj.WinningTable;` I assume it would be an O(1) operation but in your case it is O(n^2) because of the stuff you do in `.ForEach` and if you optimize the `.ForEach`, it will be O(nlogn) due to the sorting stuff.
3. Doing all the logic inside the getter is counter-intuitive. Score objects won't have the correct position index until a call to the property happens. Consider this scenario:

   ```
   var score = new Score(10);
   obj.AddScore(score);
   Console.WriteLine(score.Position); // ???
   ```

   Since you depend on the getter of the property to perform your logic, the code will not work.

My suggestion is to create a modified collection for your purpose and apply your logic there. Here is a sample implementation for the collection (with a simplified version of `Score` class for the sake of demonstration):

```
public class Score
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; } = -1;
}

public class SortedScoreCollection : Collection<Score>
{
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            item.Position = -1;
        }

        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, Score item)
    {
        if (item.Position != -1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to add score. A score can only be inside a single collection.");
        }

        index = this.FindInsertionIndex(item);

        item.Position = index + 1;

        for (int i = index; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            this[i].Position++;
        }

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        this[index].Position = -1;

        for (int i = index + 1; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            this[i].Position--;
        }

        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, Score item)
    {
        var oldItem = this[index];

        if (Equals(oldItem, item))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (item.Position != -1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to add score. A score can only be inside a single collection.");
        }

        this.RemoveItem(index);
        this.Add(item);
    }

    private int FindInsertionIndex(Score item)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < this.Count && this[index].Value > item.Value)
        {
            index++;
        }

        return index;
    }
}

// Usage:
private readonly ICollection<Score> _winningTable = new SortedScoreCollection();

public IEnumerable<Score> WinningTable => _winningTable;
```

This way all the issues explained above will be resolved and your collection and all the score objects will always be in a consistent state no matter how you add or delete them from the collection. Note that in this implementation,  deletion and insertion will be O(n) operations and retrieving `WinningTable` will be an O(1) operation.

Comment: I really needed a different point of view. Thanks for your advise I'll give it a try and perform some testing. As of now it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your intention with `EditScore` method. You are passing in a value for score that is already inside instance. It would be nice to see the implementation of class `Score` in your question.

Generally, I would say it is better to update instances in methods and setters. I believe your instances are updated with scores by some code.

And I suspect that you don't need `index`, it is directly derived from Score, as far as I can see.

Anyway, below is a simpler version of your code.

```
public IEnumerable<Score> WinningTable
{
    get
    {
        return _winningTable
            .OrderByDescending(w => w.Score)
            .Select((it, index) =>
            {
                it.EditScore((decimal)it.Score, index + 1);
                return it;
            })
           .ToList();
    }
}
```

If you can get rid of method `EditScore` (which is preferable):

```
public IEnumerable<Score> WinningTable
{
    get
    {
        return _winningTable
           .OrderByDescending(w => w.Score)
           .ToList();
    }
}
```